# jQuery, how to refer div before <script>?

Tags: jquery

I want to access the input field before the script:

```
<input>somethig</input>
<script type="text/javascript">
  now accessing "input". $('#id') is not an option
</script>
```

Comment: `$('script').prev('input')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var $input = $('script').last().prev('input');
```

The smart part is that the current script is the last loaded one (because it's synchronous).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev)

```
$('input + script').prev()
```